# Why are my build pipelines replacing specific values with asterisks? - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

My team is working to integrate an infrastructure-as-code scanning solution into our build pipelines and we've discovered that the string "GCP" is being replaced with three asterisks when tasks are being executed in our build pipelines. This isn't unique to one task either whereas I created a bash script to execute and list our our repository and all directories that start with "GCP" are replaced by the three asterisks. The only variable set using the "GCP" value is the "system.teamProject" variable and we are not using any secret values that I know of and there are no variable groups used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[Bash Asterisk Output "ls -a"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mszIC.png)

[IaC Scanning Asterisk Task Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0mum.png)

Comment: So, I know you said that *you* aren't using variable groups, but is it possible that someone else in your project has defined one and it's somehow become linked? Every single case on Microsoft Dev Community I've looked at seem to have this happening when there's a variable group with a secret value linked (even though not referenced).

Comment: And, FTW, recognize just how insecure this approach they're taking is - if you can infer what's being masked by repetition, you can figure out that there is a secret somewhere with that value...

Comment: Hi @Lubbers, How are things going? Does the issue still exist? If it still exists, please share us with the requested information, so that we can investigate this issue further.

Answer (score 2):

If you have set any secret variables in your pipeline, or have linked any variable groups that contain secret variables (include the secrets from the connected external and remote services services), generally the values of these secrets will be masked as asterisks.

[image]

When you try to print the values of the secrets to the output logs, the values will display as asterisks in the logs. If you try to output the values into a text file, the values will still display as asterisks in the file.

In addition, if a string that is not set as secret but its substrings are the values of some existing secrets in the pipeline, these substring parts may be masked as asterisks when trying to output this string.

If you do not set any secrets, for us to investigate this issue further, would you like to share us with the actual value that was masked as asterisks in the the logs? We well investigate and evaluate whether this string contains some special or sensitive characters that may be automatically identified as secrets by Azure DevOps.

Comment: This helped me. In my case, `Docker@2` with `command=login` added as a secret variable the repository's name. So, if the repository name was `my-acr-server`, after `Docker@2`, it was replaced by `***` everywhere it was as a substring.

Comment: OK, so what we can do to avoid that? And why the repository name is treated as a secret? This does not make any sense to me...